# create new connection with socket.io on every view load in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am using angularjs, nodejs and socket.io.
I have a main.html which has main view and inside it different html files are loaded in ng-view. Now what i want is that i want to create a new socket connection everytime a new html is loaded in ng-view of angular-js. Currently what it does is it creates a new socket only on first time main.html is loaded and not on every html view load.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is create a sockete in each controller when you match a route.

SO, you can do a Factory for that, something like that :

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {


  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

and then just call in your controller : `socket.on('...', function (...) {...})`
be sure that socket has been injected.

I hope it will solve your problem ! :)